# prime by reverse listing primes

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I also have a particularly interesting/attractive prime sequence and it's:  prime $p$ such that the concatenation of first k odd primes(with each prime being reversed)  in reverse order from 3 to $p$ is a prime. Only five are known:   $p=3,5,29,421,$ and $3967$.  The later has 1998 digits.    I.e. 29 is in the sequence since 923291713111753 is prime. Is this sequence infinite?  (Also I couldn't find this sequence at OEIS.)

Comment: If you have some online references (links) or other context to add to your Question, this would likely improve it as well.

Comment: i'm sorry, my english is bad.  i meant "is this sequence infinite"

Comment: i believe this sequence is infinite, but i have problem with the primality test of larger numbers.

Comment: Would you clarify how well searched these primes have been (and by whom)?

Comment: i used online Miller-Rabin test.but that last term needed an hour to compute

Comment: Simple script: `perl -Mntheory=:all -E 'my($n,$i)=("",0); forprimes { $n .= $_; my $r = reverse($n); say "   tested to $_ with digits:",length($r) unless $i++ % 64; say "$_ with digits:",length($r) if is_prime($r); } 3,1e9'`  Doing it in Pari/GP would be pretty easy as well.  About 2-3 seconds to get to 3967.

Comment: thank you very much  mr Jacobbsen

Comment: wait a minute,  you meant it only took 3 seconds to test whether a  1998 digit number is a prime?  woow...

Comment: BPSW for 2000 digit input takes about 0.2 seconds, some extra M-R or Frobenius tests don't add much time.  It's a probable prime.  Depending on resources and implementation, a proof would take ~5 minutes (Primo many cores) to 3 hours (O/S ECPP single thread, O/S APR-CL less than that).

Comment: if i use the fastest supercomputer, could i perform probabilistic primality test on 10 million digits number less than say 30 minutes?

Comment: Assuming it is a prime, no.  The tests will be slower than the Lucas-Lehmer test used for Mersenne numbers, and in 2006 it looks like it took 11 days on 16 CPUs for a 9.8M digit number.  We have faster programs and computers now, but I think it would still be ~1 day (again, for a Lucas-Lehmer test which is very efficient and doesn't apply to a general form number).  One other note: the software such as CUDALucas, MLucas, and other GIMPS programs are far more optimized for these large-number Lucas tests than almost any general software like GMP.